Error when evaluating SSR module - ReferenceError: window is not defined
Getting below error while implementing SSR on Vue 3 project.
Error when evaluating SSR module /src/router/index.js:
|- ReferenceError: window is not defined
at useHistoryStateNavigation (file:///Users/***/project/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs:487:35)
at Proxy.createWebHistory (file:///Users/***/project/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs:582:31)
at eval (/Users/***/project/src/router/index.js:119:35)
at async instantiateModule (file:///Users/***/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3b8eb186.js:55920:9)

Also, I tried adding undefined check for places where window is used like below but still getting the ReferenceError: window is not defined
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.open('/some/pages', '_self')
}


Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's impossible to get "ReferenceError: window is not defined" if you use "if (typeof window !== 'undefined')"
